# How can I scrape inspected elements with beautifulsoup (or any other scraper) in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I was writting a scraping program. I firstly used selenium for getting the element's source (an mp4 file), then I see selenium is mainly used for automation and testing but not scraping. I thought using other scraper modules would be more reasonable. But when I use `requests+beautifulsoup` or `urllib2/3+beautifulsoup` I couldn't manage to get the inspect elements. They are getting page source but in the web page I'm working, the page source is not the same as the HTML that pops up when I inspect it. (I don't know much about the difference between inspect and page source but I guess it has something to do with JS.) Any ideas how I can solve this issue?
here is my code:

```
from  bs4 import  BeautifulSoup

import  requests

response = requests.get("https://animefrenzy.org/stream/one-piece-episode-974")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")

print(soup)
```

here is the html I want as string:
[Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzJZw.png)

here is the result I get when I execute the above code:
[terminal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G3FF.png)

Comment: You didn't mentioned what exactly you want to scrape? Is highlighted in inspect image you want to scrape?

Comment: @Kshitiz It doesn't matter really. I can't even get the html of the page. Any element would work. But as I obviously explained in the question that I want the whole html tag.

Comment: You can use `selenium+BeautifulSoup` to scrape this website, just tell which part you want to scrape. Pictorial representation is also accepted but in clear way. Image should contain 1/2 upper element and 1/2 lower element of your destination!

Comment: @Kshitiz I want to reach to source of the video that is in the iframe /html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[7]/div/iframe and in the iframe it is in this path: html/body/div[2]/div[2]/video/source[1]

Comment: Is this same for all of the episode page? Or you just want to scrape from one page multiple times?

Comment: I thought it was same but it isn't. that is the reason I'm trying to get all html as a string so that I can work with it (with the help of regular expression maybe).

Comment: If you just want the source code of the website then it's easier. Should I provide tha code for that?

Comment: @Kshitiz yes it would be awesome if you could fetch all of the html. But if it will be the same as 'terminal result' photo I shared in the question it won't work for me :/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the HTML(Source) only then here's the code to get that.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox/Chrome(executable_path=r'/path/to/webdriver')

driver.get('https://animefrenzy.org/stream/one-piece-episode-974')
time.sleep(10)
html=driver.page_source
print(html)
```

This shoud give you the HTML that you want, we used `time.sleep(10)` because page have to load javascript and change content of the page. If you are not getting desire HTML then try to change sleep time into little more, so that page will loaded completly.